# how can Icount the frequency of words in documents in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am a beginner in Java and I have a program for calculating the number of words in multiple documents as array and then gives the output in a new file is created in the name of a certain account .. I have used the following function, can I replace it with another easier ones ??

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fn = "C:\\Users\\Angel\\Desktop\\myproject\\Preprocessing/";
    File ff = new File(fn);
    ff.mkdir();

    int flage;

    String dir = "C:\\Users\\Angel\\Desktop\\myproject     \\ConvertingToText"; //read
    String s = "";
    File folder = new File(dir);
    String se = "";
    File fs[] = folder.listFiles();
    /*for(File f:fs) // print files name
        {System.out.println(f.getName());}*/
    for (File f: fs) {
        String fn1 = fn + f.getName() + "/";
        File ff1 = new File(fn1);
        ff1.mkdir();
        System.out.println(f.getName());
        System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath()); //
        File folder2 = new File(f.getAbsolutePath());
        File[] f3 = folder2.listFiles();
        for (File fi: f3) {
            s = readTextFile(fi.getAbsolutePath());
            String fn4 = fn1 + fi.getName() + "/";
            s = s.toLowerCase();

            String[] keys = s.split(" ");
            String[] uniquewords;
            int count = 0;
            //System.out.println(s);
            uniquewords = getUniquewords(keys);

            for (String key: uniquewords) {
                if (null == key) {
                    break;
                }
                for (String sr: keys) {
                    if (key.equals(sr)) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("[" + key + "]" + count);
                count = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
private static String[] getUniquewords(String[] keys) {
    String[] uniquewords = new String[keys.length];

    uniquewords[0] = keys[0];
    int uniquewordIndex = 1;
    boolean keyAlreadyExists = false;

    for (int i = 1; i < keys.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= uniquewordIndex; j++) {
            if (keys[i].equals(uniquewords[j])) {
                keyAlreadyExists = true;
            }
        }

        if (!keyAlreadyExists) {
            uniquewords[uniquewordIndex] = keys[i];
            uniquewordIndex++;
        }
        keyAlreadyExists = false;
    }
    return uniquewords;
}
```

Comment: I need to calculate the number of words in document, for example the word " hello" then I want to know how much it appears in document1, document2, and so on, and put the results in a file.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a Map to store the count of unique words. That way, you can iterate of the text only once and build up a result you can print later.

A simple implementation is below:

```
public Map<String, Integer> wordFrequencyIn(String text) {
    String[] words = text.trim().toLowerCase().split("\\s+"); // NOTE: splits on any whitespace character, not just " "
    HashMap<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();

    for (String word : words) {
        int count = result.getOrDefault(word, 0);
        result.put(word, count + 1);
    }

    return result;
}
```

To print the Map, you can iterate over the entries. Like this:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : result.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("[" + entry.getKey() + "]" + entry.getValue());
}
```

If you are not familiar with using Maps, I suggest taking a look at the Oracle tutorial and documentation:

- [The Map Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)
- [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Comment: oh I'll do that next time, Thank you @phss

Comment: I also have another issue, when  calculate frequencies, it is also compute the white spaces, how can I prevent from compute it?? @phss

Comment: @ nani je  Why Next Time ? If this solution works you need to mark it as answer. This is basic courtesy. Up Vote his answer and accept it.